# Set back the actionbar in mainactivity/navigation drawer?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

I have set a custom action bar to one of the fragments and on back press need to revert back to the main actionbar in main activity /navigation drawer.

I set the actionbar for mainactivity in the mainfest:

android:theme="@style/AppTheme"

For one of my fragments i set custom action bar as follows:

xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Dest_Cancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
       />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/Dest_Title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
     />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/Dest_Send"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:textColor="@color/ceiva_white"
     />
```

in restoreActionbar method in mainActivity, I do the following:

```
 public void restoreActionBar() {        
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);

   if(mTitle.equals(getString(R.string.destinations_title)) }
        //custom actionbar defined 
    LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.custom_destinations_action_bar, null);

        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setCustomView(v);

        //next();

    }
```

I call the resstoreActionbar() method in my fragment and set the title to make changes accordingly. The custom action bar gets set but i am not able to revert back on going back to main activity. Or rather i dont know how to revert back. please advice.

Comment: `setSupportActionBar()` should work within an `AppCompatActivity` class to set the actionbar. If you have code that you are working with, please [edit] your question so we can see what you are trying to do.

Comment: I have edited my question as per your request. Please advice. I tried adding the above, setSupportActionBar() but seems like it doesnt exist.

Comment: If you are using `getSupportActionBar()`, then `setSupportActionBar()` is definitely a method. It just accepts a `Toolbar` object instead of an `ActionBar` object.

Comment: Thanks fro responding but can you please explain how to get the toolbar tht i previously set in the manifest as theme? Should i create a new xml file?

Comment: Could you maybe save an instance variable for the original Toolbar inside of `onCreate`? What happens when you do `actionBar.setCustomView(null);`? It might crash, but I'm just curious.

Comment: Works.. thank you.